# audio analog input + usb data cable = sound noises

Tags: audio, noise

I connect my android smartphone from audio jack output to my pc audio input and get a good analog sound signal. But when I connect this smartphone to  the pc with usb data cable the analog sound becomes hissing e.g. music from smartphone overlaps with noises on pc.
Why does this happen?
How can I eliminate these noises? maybe I have to use some shielded cables? If yes - then audio or usb? or I need some sound direct box or something like that?

Comment: not a signal processing question – this is probably about insufficient noise suppression on the shared grounds. You'll be better of on electronics.stackexchange.com ; my guess would even be that very similar questions have been asked on there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a signal processing question, but an electrical engineering question. However, similar questions have been asked on electronics.stackexchange.com before, which bars migration to that site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by adding ground loop noise filter like [this](https://www.xmpow.com/mpow-ground-loop-noise-isolator-for-car-audio-system-home-stereo-ma1.html)